# CSS&Laravel - Background Blur Filter

Tags: html, css

Im trying to add a blur to the background but it wont work that way. It blurs everything except the background..

```
.login-page,
.register-page {
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;

  background-image: url("../../images/bg.jpg");
  filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
    background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

Looks like this on the page : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxCgR.png)

The login.blade.php code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>SunnyStateNET | Login</title>
  @include('layouts.template-parts.head-scripts')
</head>

<body class="hold-transition login-page">
  <div class="dark-mode login-box">
    <!-- /.login-logo -->
    <div class="card card-outline card-primary">
      <div class="card-header text-center">
        <b>Melde dich mit deinen Daten an.</b>
      </div>
      <div class="dark-mode card-body">
        @if($message = Session::get('error'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert">
          <strong>{{$message}}</strong>
        </div>
        @endif
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('postlogin') }}">
          @csrf
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Charaktername">
          </div>
          <div class="dark-mode input-group mb-3">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Passwort">
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">Anmelden</button>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-box -->
  @include('layouts.template-parts.footer-scripts')
  @method('scripts')
</body>

</html>
```

Hope someone could hit me with a hint because i think iam going crazy from this

Comment: This really isn't a laravel or php issue, so I removed those tags. Can you post your rendered HTML instead of your blade template? And you can even strip this down to the most basic containers. Also, `blur` won't blur a background image..what you're looking for is [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

Comment: Does not really answer the question, probably its just me but i dont really get it right now.. sorry! (Iam using the adminlte css with has thousands of lines already defined..)